# Can lattice field theory be used with $1$-loop effective actions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, interactions, effective-field-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

It's all in the title. If I have, say, a $1$-loop effective action, is it possible to perform reliable lattice computations? I am asking because I heard lattice is not that accurate if the coupling is small, but I may have misunderstood the actual statement.

Comment: This sounds like the notion of "improved actions" in lattice field theory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes [here is one paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.02563). [Here is a book on the subject](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-14189-9). As far as I understand it, it is used as a means to study nuclear bound states based off a Chiral theory of nucleons and massless pions. The pions (as far as I am aware)

- are analogous to Wilson Lines in the usual Lattice Gauge theory
- All pion correlators average to zero.

I am unaware of how to deal with an infinite tower of dimensionful operators in the effective action. However people *do* work on them in research. I am sure you can extend this to any other effective field theory.

Comment: Effective field theories work when you are probing energies $E$ much smaller than the scale $M$ associated with the dimensionful operators. To a given order in $E/M$, there are only a finite number of dimensionful operators. So the procedure is to pick $p$ such that "I am happy if my results have an error parametrically smaller than $(E/M)^p$", then only keep the finite number of operators up to order $(E/M)^p$.

Comment: I think you are right. In this case $M =$ the lattice spacing in your lattice theory.